# netbeans no option to create java project

Tags: windows-10, java, netbeans

(I have windows 10 and a 64-bit OS. Also I am using an alienware computer if that is important.)

I'm new to programming and decided to do some programming at home as well as what I was doing for school and download JDK and Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0. I wanted to make a regular java project but it does not give me an option to. I tried to look up this problem and could not find a specific answer for myself.
So I tried some solutions that didn't quite fit my own situation and decided that I should go to tools --> plugins --> installed and proceeded to install every given option, but that did not work.

Here is a picture:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhZ1T.png)

So in summary how do I get a normal java project, or am I just not seeing the option.

Thank You in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried to select File -> New project?

Comment: I added the wrong photo. Look at the new one it shows the problem. Sorry.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the installed plugins?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 18.10.